# Separate navigation drawers for certain routes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I'm building a Vuetify app in combination with Vuex and vue-router. Some of the views uses the default navigation drawer, but others has different items in their navigation drawers. [This documentation say](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) I can pass props to view components. So I implement it like this:

### routes/index.js

```
{
  path: '/courses/:courseId/lessons/:lessonId',
  name: 'Course 1',
  components: {
    default: () => import('@/views/ViewLesson.vue'),
    sidebar: () => import('@/components/CourseNavBar/CourseNavBar.vue')
  },
  props: {
    items: [
      { text: "Link 1", href:"/link1" },
      { text: "Link 2", href:"/link2" }
    ]
  }
}
```

### src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="primary"
      dark
    >
    <h1>My Project</h1>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer><router-view :items="items" name="sidebar"/></v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>
      <router-view />
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

But apparently,

### src/components/CourseNavBar.vue

```
<template>
  <!-- <v-navigation-drawer :value="1"> -->
    <v-list dense>
      <navbar-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :item="item" >
        {{ item.text }}
      </navbar-item>
    </v-list>
  <!-- </v-navigation-drawer> -->
</template>

<script>
import NavBarItem from './NavBarItem.vue'
export default {
  props: {
    items: Array
  },
  components: {
    'navbar-item': NavBarItem
  }
}
</script>
```

But `<CourseNavBar>`'s props is still undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues...

Replace `=` with `:`...

```
 items: [
    { text:"Link 1", href:"/link1" },
    { text:"Link 2", href:"/link2" }
  ]
```

And the `sidebar` component (not router-view) should be in the slot for the `navigation-drawer`...

```
<v-navigation-drawer><sidebar :items="items"></sidebar></v-navigation-drawer>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/oNInfpTwvK

Answer (score -1):

In your
`routes\index.js`
you need to define the props option for each of the named views:

```
{
  path: '/courses/:courseId/lessons/:lessonId',
  name: 'Course 1',
  components: {
    default: () => import('@/views/ViewLesson.vue'),
    sidebar: () => import('@/components/CourseNavBar/CourseNavBar.vue')
  },
  props: {
    default: true,
    sidebar: true,
    items: [
      { text: "Link 1", href: "/link1" },
      { text: "Link 2", href: "/link2" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And following on from what @Zim said, you've used "=" instead of ":" when assigning the href value to the props items array.

You can use `<router-view name="sidebar"/>` to output the named component.

Comment: I've followed your example. Unfortunately, `items` is still undefined when inspected using Vue tools.

Comment: @starleaf1 does this example help? https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tesla-6z14m